# regular expression for something::something::something disallowing brackets

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that only accepts strings with the pattern:

```
something1::something2::something3
```

Where `something`s can be anything but brackets (`[` and `]`) and empty strings.

Accepted:

```
server_3::database_2::newtable
```

Not accepted:

```
 [server_3]::database_2::new table
```

Comment: `Where somethings can be anything but brackets`, Are control characters allowed?

Comment: What about `server:3::data:base_2::new:table`, should it be matched as well? Should `[server]_3::database_2::new table` produce a match for the portion that fits your template? i.e. `_3::database_2::new`?

Comment: You can use https://www.regex101.com/ website to test and create your regex expressions. It has nice context help as well :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes that is allowed as well.

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE i think we should eliminate the use of control characters in a perfect world but let us allow them for now.

Comment: @Gerino thank you. I am currently using http://www.regexr.com/.

Answer (score 2):

Use the negated character class `[^\[\]]` to match anything except square brackets, and the `+` quantifier to match at least one character (aka not the empty string):

```
[^\[\]]+::[^\[\]]+::[^\[\]]+
```

Comment: Just add spaces.. but note that it'll match `[dfg]df::dfgdfg::gfdg` (from `df`)

Comment: This looks great, but I think it is still accepting brackets on the first string `something1` according to http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: @Pedram: Depending on how you use the regex, you may have to add start-of-string and end-of-string anchors. Try `^[^\[\]]+::[^\[\]]+::[^\[\]]+$`.

Answer (score 0):

This will only match word characters:

```
\w*::\w*::\w*
```

> a-zA-Z_0-9 divided by ::

This might be better though:

```
[^\[\]]*::[^\[\]]*::[^\[\]]*
```

as it should match any character but [ and ], so `server_3()::database_2::newtable` will pass